# How can I sync and remove users from a group across two sites?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to sync "Groups" and each group's members between two sites. The part that is messing up is when trying to remove users from One Group Site that doesn't exist in the other Group Site. I'm fairly confident it's just a matter of indenting wrong but I can't seem to figure it out.

Code:

```
import json
import requests

api_key = "blahblah"
api_user = "johnwick"
token = "disdatokendontstealit"
url1 = "yolo.com"
ur2 = "yolo.web"

headers1 = {
    "X-KZO-Auth-AccessKey": api_key,
    "X-KZO-Accept-API-Versions": "1",
    "X-KZO-Auth-Username": api_user,
    "Content-Type": "application/vnd.api+json",
    "X-KZO-Pipeline-Action": "Process",
}

headers2 = {
    "Authorization": token,
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
}

get_bridge_groups_URL = f"{url1}/api/author/groups"
get_bridge_groups = requests.get(get_bridge_groups_URL, headers=headers1)
group_data = (
    get_bridge_groups.json()
)  ## These three lines go out and get Group data from Site1


for group in group_data["groups"]:
    group_name = group["name"]  ## Get the name of the group
    bridge_group_id = group["id"]  ## Get the id of the group
    bav_create_group_url = f"{bav_url}/api/groups"
    group_payload = {"groups": {"name": group_name, "description": ""}}
    create_bav_group = requests.post(
        bav_create_group_url,
        headers=headers2,
        json=group_payload,  ## Go create the Group with same name in Site2
    )
    if create_bav_group.status_code == 201:
        print(f"Group '{group_name}' created successfully!")
    else:
        print(
            f"Failed to create group '{group_name}'. Status code:",
            create_bav_group.status_code,
        )
    bav_group_data = create_bav_group.json()
    bav_group_id = bav_group_data["groups"][
        "id"
    ]  ## Get the ID of the new group in Site 2
    get_group_learners_url = (
        f"{url1}/api/learn/author/groups/{bridge_group_id}/learners"
    )
    get_group_learners = requests.get(
        get_group_learners_url, headers=headers1
    )  ## Get group members from Site 1
    groups_users_json = get_group_learners.json()
    for learner in groups_users_json["learners"]:
        try:
            bav_find_user_url = f"https://andrew-v5.instilled.com/api/users?q={learner['email']}"  ## Search and attempt to match user by email from Site1 in Site2
            bav_find_user = requests.get(bav_find_user_url, headers=headers2)

            bav_user_json = bav_find_user.json()
            username = bav_user_json["users"][0]["username"]
            enroll_in_bav_group_url = (
                f"https://andrew-v5.instilled.com/api/groups/{bav_group_id}/users"
            )
            enroll_in_bav_group = requests.post(  ## If user found in Site1, enroll into the newly created group in Site1
                enroll_in_bav_group_url,
                headers=instilled_headers,
                data=json.dumps({"users": [username]}),
            )
            print(f"{learner['email']} has been enrolled in '{group_name}'. Sweet!")
        except IndexError:
            print(f"User {learner['email']} was not found in BAV.") ## If user is not found by email, print that they are not in Site2.
    get_bav_group_learners_url = f"{bav_url}/api/groups/{bav_group_id}?include=users" ## Below here is where it starts to crap out, I'm attempting to get the new Group members from Site2 for the new Group and match them against the Group in Site1. If members exist in Site2 Group but not Site1 Group, I want to remove them from Site 2 Group.
    get_new_group_learners = requests.get(
        get_bav_group_learners_url, headers=instilled_headers
    )
    bav_group_users_json = get_new_group_learners.json()
    for user in bav_group_users_json["linked"]["users"]:
        email = user["email"]
        if email in {learner["email"]}:
            print(f"{learner['email']} is enrolled in BAV Group and Bridge Group")
        else:
            bav_user_delete_url = (
                f"{bav_url}/api/groups/{bav_group_id}/users/{username}"
            )
            bav_user_delete = requests.delete(
                bav_user_delete_url, headers=instilled_headers
            )
            print(
                f"{username} using email ({email}) has been removed from the BAV Group"
            )
```

I've tried messing with the indents but still have no luck. I may just break that part of the script out and figure out another way to do it. But ideally, I can correct each Group as they are made.

I'd expect the script to match emails again between the two sites and remove members of the Group in Site2 that don't exist in Site1.

**EDIT**
[Terminal Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWVMW.jpg)

Comment: Why do you think that this has something to do with indentation?

Comment: And why do you think that you are messing something up?

Comment: The output in the terminal does not print the "print(f"{learner['email']} is enrolled in BAV Group and Bridge Group")" after syncing the matching users. It just goes and creates the next Group.

Comment: Then `email in {learner["email"]}` was false. Why did you expect that is was true instead?

Comment: _The output in the terminal ..._ It would help if you **showed** us this output, and explain exactly how it isn't what you were expecting.

Comment: `if email in {learner["email"]}` Why are you bothering to create a set that has only one element?  Why not just compare directly?  `if email == learner["email"]`?

Comment: I did the `if email in {learner["email"]}:` to loop through the newly created Group in Site2 using the `for user in bav_group_users_json["linked"]["users"]:` before it.

I will add the terminal output to the original post. Thank you all for trying to help!